# CRM 2013 On-line Mail Merge Quote for Customer print totals at the bottom

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

We are creating a new Mail Merge Template and we would like the following fields to be placed after the Product listing

Please find your quote details below:

Quote ID:                                            «Quote_ID»

Quote Discount percentage:       «Quote_Discount_»

Quote Discount Amount:             «Quote_Discount_Amount»

Total Detail Amount:                      «Total_Detail_Amount»

Total Tax:                                             «Total_Tax»

Total Amount:                                   «Total_Amount»

.

If so how can we do this any help would be great.

Damon

Answer (score 0):

CRM's mail merge is very limited and if you want to do something more advanced, you will need to resort to a 3rd party tool to do it. You can browse the net there are several options you can choose from. We use this mail merge [toolkit](http://www.docentric.com) for .NET and it has proven to be a very flexible mail merge tool - you can even render **summary fields**, hyperlinks, lists, charts, images. But you will need to wrap it as a CRM add-in.